# acquireTokenAsync missing deviceId in the token

Tags: adal

I am using the [cordova adal library](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova) with **broker support** enabled for Intune. When I call the **acquireTokenAsync** method below using the *optional* **userId** parameter the generated access token that is returned includes a deviceId value, but when I leave the userId out of the call the access token does not include the deviceId.
[image]
Is the device id supposed to be present in the access token on both calls, or is the above behavior the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding, the device id supposed to be present in the access token on both calls. Since even if we don't specify the user, we also need the user information during get the access token. It seems that it is no related whether the user is specified.

I am not familiar with cordova, but I test it with C# Adal SDK, even if I don't use userId as parameter, the access token also includes the deviceId.

But According to the [Claims in id_tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims#idtokens), the device token is not manditory in the access token. If you are sure that deviceId is not in your access token, I recommand you could give your [feedback](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova/issues) to Azure team.